# $f:M\rightarrow N$ module homomorphism, $(N/\mathrm{Im}f)_m=N_m/\mathrm{Im}f_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> $f:M\rightarrow N$ is an $R$-module homomorphism and $f_\mathfrak{m}:M_\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow N_\mathfrak{m}$ is the induced $R$-module homomorphism
>   $$f_\mathfrak{m}(m/s)=f(m)/s$$
>   where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in a commutative ring $R$ with unity and $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is the module localization at $\mathfrak{m}$. I want to show that
>   $$(N/\operatorname{Im}f)_\mathfrak{m}=N_\mathfrak{m}/\operatorname{Im}f_\mathfrak{m}.$$

I have constructed a function $g:N_\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow (N/\operatorname{Im}f)_\mathfrak{m}$ that is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism by
$$g(n/s)=(n+\operatorname{Im}f)/s.$$
I am now trying to show that $\operatorname{Ker}g=\operatorname{Im}f_\mathfrak{m}$ and this is where I am having trouble. I can see the inclusion of $\operatorname{Im}f_\mathfrak{m}$ in $\operatorname{Ker}g$. The first containment is the issue. My attempt:

Let $n/s\in \operatorname{Ker}g$ so $(n+\operatorname{Im}f)/s=0/s$, so we have that there exists some $t\in S$ where $ts(n+\operatorname{Im}f)=0$, i.e. $tsn \in \operatorname{Im}f$ so there exists some $m \in M$ where $tsn=f(m)$.

In order for $n/s \in \operatorname{Im}f_\mathfrak{m}$ I need some $p/q \in M_\mathfrak{m}$ such that $n/s=f_\mathfrak{m}(p/q)$, i.e., $n/s=f(p)/q$. For this I need the existence of some $z \in S$ where $zqn=zsf(p)$ and I am not sure how to get this from $tsn=f(m)$. If it helps I am open to strengthening the assumptions but want to keep it to a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for hands-on approach: Show that it's enough to take $s = 1$, i.e., given an element of the form $n/1 \in \ker g$, show that $n/1 \in \text{im } f_m$, and then show that this implies that $\ker g \subseteq \text{im } f_m$ (for this last part, notice that $n/s = (n/1) \cdot (1/s)$).

High-brow approach: localization is an exact functor. This implies that for any inclusion of $R$-modules $A \subseteq B$, the exact sequence

$$0 \to A \to B \to B/A \to 0$$

yields, upon localizing, an exact sequence of $R_m$-modules

$$0 \to A_m \to B_m \to (B/A)_m \to 0$$

so that $(B/A)_m \cong B_m/A_m$.

Comment: Why $0 \to A_m \to B_m \xrightarrow{f} C \to 0$ and $0 \to A_m \xrightarrow{g} B_m \to D \to 0$ imply $C \cong D$? Given $x=f(b)$, a natural candidate for the isomorphism will be $g(b)$, but it seems not to be well-defined.